# What if Dark Matter is Majorana Fermion?

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter, cosmological-constant, majorana-fermions

Few reasons to believe Dark Matter is Majorana fermion:

1. https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.03877: second contra argument by Jordan and Pauli. "A non vanishing zero-point energy of elementary fields should have a significant gravitational effect. This effect is not observed." (1928)
2. Hawking radiation of black holes is the symmetry breaking of fermionic and bosonic fields.

Constraints on Dark matter and its elusive nature, intuitively similar to quasiparticles like electron holes or more interestingly Majorana fermions. since they interact with gravity.

What are the implications if Dark matter is made of Majorana Fermions?